# Where I put the code dependencies

Tags: android

I´m referring to the documentation http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html link, but I don´t know where to put dependencies. In my android manifest.xml?

Open your main module’s build.gradle file and add following dependency for using action bar in lower API level

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Comment: Instructions say: **Open your main module’s build.gradle file** - so no, not in manifest.xml. Are you using Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this only this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

inside in existing dependencies block in build.gradle file inside of app folder.